# How I can configure the `League\Flysystem` for SFTP to use a proxy server instead of a direct connection?

Tags: php

I have a network with multiple gateways and a remote SFTP server that accepts connections from a specific IP. Hence, in the machine with the necessary IP has a SocksV5 proxy and any connection needing this particular IP uses that proxy.

Furtermore, I made a simple script to upload a csv into an SFTP server:

```
include ./vendor/autoload.php

use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\Sftp\SftpAdapter;
use Carbon\Carbon;

$adapter = new SftpAdapter([
            'host'          => getenv('FTP_HOST'),
            'port'          => getenv('SFTP_PORT') ?: 22,
            'username'      => getenv('SFTP_USERNAME'),
            'password'      => getenv('SFTP_PASSWORD'),
            'root'          => getenv('SFTP_ROOT'),
            'timeout'       => 30,
            'directoryPerm' => 0755,
        ]);

$filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);

$contents  = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
$filesystem->put(Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $contents);
```

But how I can configure the `SftpAdapter` to use a proxy server in order to upload the contents into the SFTP server?